# How to print a Power BI visualization as a PDF on a weekly scheduled time using Power Automate?

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I have created Power BI visualizations with SharePoint based project online dataset. I want to automate sending a weekly report of my visualization and reports.

I used Microsoft Power Automate, but there are no existing templates in triggers.

I do not know which actions and triggers to choose or how to build this. I tried using manual trigger with schedule recurrence, power bi trigger but none of these helped.

I do not know the feasibility of this yet and do not know how to build this flow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this link for built in on demand subscription functionality,

[Export to PDF on-demand email subscription](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/export-to-pdf-and-on-demand-e-mail-subscriptions-now-available/)

1. Click on subscribe button

[image]

2. Setup your time schedule Hourly, Daily and Weekly option available,

[image]

Comment: @Mboolean Thank you so much. I do not know how it got down voted. I have tried to change it and I know this feature exists but I was trying to achieve the same using Flow. And, following up on your answer I have one more question, Do you know how to get complete visualization printed, please? Sometimes visualizations in my reports are big and it requires scrolling. This does not get printed properly, if i use print option and select pdf. I tried using the subscription method also, I do not get the desired results